# Removing Cast.Listener in teardown

Tags: android, casting, listener, dispose, teardown

Working on a chromecast sender app, I am having hard time to find api for unregistering com.google.android.gms.cast.Cast.Listener in teardown implementation.

this is how api client is being constructed:

```
CastListener castListener = new CastListener();
Cast.CastOptions.Builder apiOptionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions
    .builder(device, castListener);
GoogleApiClient apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
    .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptionsBuilder.build())
    .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener)
    .build();
```

and here bits of my teardown() implementation:

```
apiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks);
apiClient.unregisterConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener);
apiClient.disconnect();
apiClient = null;
```

There seems to be unregister* methods for connections callbacks and failed listeners, but not for removing cast listener. So even after the teardown, the CastListener methods are being executed (onVolumeChanged) so I assume the disposal of GoogleApiClient is not complete. Is there anything else that can be done in teardown? Something like hidden removeApi() method on GoogleApiClient?

Currently there is apiClient!=null check in my CastListener.onVolumeChanged() but I would like to avoid that condition and rather have a solution where cast listener is completely disposed in teardown().

Any ideas?